# How do i replace tone variations of the same color in a C# Bitmap?

Tags: c#, image-processing, aforge

**Scope**:

Hi everyone, i am trying to convert this captcha to a "black and white" (binarized) image, where the characters are white and the whole rest (background,lines,random pictures) are black.

The link to the captcha can be found [here](http://www.fazenda.rj.gov.br/projetoCPS/codigoImagem). Refreshing will give you another captcha.

**Reason:**

I know most of people think it is wrong to mess with captchas so here i am defending myself. This will be used for knowledge / self challenge only. No other use is planned for these images.

**Problem:**

After studying these images for a while, i figured out that a good aproach would be to replace the colors : "White and Yellow" to "Color.Black", and every other color should be replaced to "Color.White."

After this, i would just "Invert" the colors, leading me to the output i want.

**Code Sample:**

In this code, i am trying to replace the color "Black" of every image for a SkyBlue Pixel.

```
        WebRequests wr = new WebRequests(); // My class to handle WebRequests
        Bitmap bmp;
        string url = "http://www.fazenda.rj.gov.br/projetoCPS/codigoImagem";

        bmp = wr.GetBitmap (url);

        for (int i = 1; i < bmp.Height ; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1 ; j < bmp.Width ; j++)
            {
                if (bmp.GetPixel(j,i).Equals(Color.Black))
                {
                    bmp.SetPixel(j,i, Color.SkyBlue);
                }
            }
        }
```

This code do not work at all, i'm not sure why, but no pixel is getting replaced in this example.

**Question:**

How can i make this work ? What am i missing here ?

Also, the ideal scenario for me would be to "reduce" the color pallete of this image to "basic" colors, that would make my job here much easier.

I already tried the [AForge Framework](http://www.aforgenet.com/projects/iplab/), which i am using to reduce colors, but it is not working at all, the result is not the one i expected.

What can i do here in order to binarize this image correctly ?

Thanks in advance,

Marcello Lins.

Comment: The CAPTCHA I see contains a yellow 'Q' and 'C' and a black 'Q', but also a white 'W' and a white 'C' that your approach would make disappear to black.

Comment: They would not Disappear since the background is gray, never black.
I would like to make all the characters have the same color, and since the character colors can only be "white, yellow and black", i would end up having all characters as black, and every other color, would be treated as a background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your algorithm does not work is that you are looking for an *exact* match. But the black in the image isn't really black due to JPEG compression artifacts; in three CAPTCHAS I've loaded there was not even a single black (0, 0, 0) pixel. The closest value was (0, 0, 4) which looks black, but isn't.

An approximate approach would be:

- Remove all grays (channels differing from each other less than 5%) having a channel average below 220 with gray. This kills the thin lightgray lines as well as much of the ringing (JPEG) artifacts against a gray background.
- Replace all pixels where the red, green, or blue channel is more than 25% above *both* the other two channels with gray. This takes care of reds, greens and blues as well as most of their ringing artifacts.
- Run a simple despeckle to remove all nongray pixels surrounded by five grays and by no other pixel of the same colour within 20%.

At the end of this process, the background is all gray, all nongray pixels left are characters.

Some useful functions:

```
// Very basic (and CIE-incorrect) check
public static int isGray(Color c)
{
    if (Math.Abs(c.R - c.G) > 5 * 2.55) return 0; // Not gray. R and G too different
    if (Math.Abs(c.R - c.B) > 5 * 2.55) return 0;
    if (Math.Abs(c.G - c.B) > 5 * 2.55) return 0;
    return 1;
}

// the blind man's test for shading :-)
public static int isShadeOfRed(Color c)
{
    if (4*c.R < 5*c.G) return 0; // Red not strong enough in respect to green
    if (4*c.R < 5*c.B) return 0; // Red not strong enough in respect to blue
    return 1; // Red is stronger enough than green and blue to be called "shade of red"
}

// (shades of green and blue left as an exercise)

// Very basic (and CIE-incorrect) check
public static int areSameColor(Color a, Color b)
{
    if (Math.Abs(a.R - b.R) > 5 * 2.55) return 0;
    if (Math.Abs(a.G - b.G) > 5 * 2.55) return 0; 
    if (Math.Abs(a.B - b.B) > 5 * 2.55) return 0;
    return 1; // "more or less" the same color
}

// This is more or less pseudo code...
public static int isNoise(int x, int y)
{
    if ((x < 1) || (y < 1)) return 0; // or maybe "return 1"
    if ((x+1 >= bmp.Width)||(y+1 >= bmp.Height)) return 0;
    pix = bmp.GetPixel(x,y);
    for (i = -1; i <= 1; i++)
        for (j = -1; j <= 1; j++)
        {
            if ((i == 0) && (j == 0)) continue;
            test = bmp.GetPixel(x+i, y+j);
            if (isGray(test)) grays++;
            if (isSameColor(pix, test)) same++;
        }
    // Pixel surrounded by grays, and has no neighbours of the same colour
    // (who knows, maybe we could skip gray calculation and check altogether?)
    // is noise.
    if ((grays == 5) && (same == 0))
       return 1;
    return 0;
}

// NOTE: do not immediately set to gray pixels found to be noise, for their neighbours
// will be calculated using the new gray pixel. Damage to image might result.
// Use a copy of bmp instead.
```

Comment: Just to doublecheck have you tested it ?

Comment: With a couple of CAPTCHAs, yes. But you may want to experiment with those thresholds - such as "220". I think it might be raised further. Also, it depends on the OCR used later: I halted the despeckling at five grays because otherwise it was clipping the character graces. Might be that four, or six, gives a better final result.

Comment: @Iserni Would you mind sending me some code via pastebin so i can see what you mean with "Remove all gray channels"?
Thanks

Comment: @Iserni thanks for taking your time and writing some code for us. I will be reading it now